# Design the chat conversation page for iOS like What's app

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I'm creating a chat application in iOS, so the problem is I have no idea to design the chat page (i.e.) whether it uses tableview or collection view or own view design.

In what's app chat what way they have designed the conversation page I think they won't use the table view or collection view because we sent the message it's properly inserting without loading tableview or collection view and also when we scroll up for load more messages, it does took more time for loading and properly loading the above message.

Comment: I've used UITableView for chat conversation page. Define two separate table cell templates and add your source of messages in a UITableViewDataSource. You can always invoke reloadData() to add new rows as needed.

Comment: typo *reloadData()

Comment: https://github.com/logicsb/whatsapp-ios

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController